# Change Text Color When It Matches A Regular Expression - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to change some text color when it matches a regex, but can't seem to get it to work.

In the code below the var `HTMLattr` matches anything inside and including the quotations marks in the `<code>` element. I then want to be able to change the color of this text. The way I would normally do this in JavaScript is with `cssText`, but this property isn't working?

In the example below the regex returns the value `"test"` including the quotation marks as expected. What I'm trying to do is turn the `"test"` text red.

I'm new to regular expressions so any assistance would be amazing.

Emily

```js
// CHANGE COLOUR OF MATCHED REGEX
var codeHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('code-html')

for (var i = 0; i < codeHTML.length; i+=1) {

  var str = codeHTML[i].textContent
  var HTMLattr = str.match(/".+"/g)

  if(HTMLattr) {
      HTMLattr.style.cssText = 'color:red;'
  }

  console.log(HTMLattr)
  
}
```

```html
<code class="code code-html">
<span class="code-tag open">&lt;div class="test"&gt;</span>
Hi
<span class="code-tag closed">&lt;/div&gt;</span>
</code>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the style of HTMLattr because it is just a string and not an element of the DOM. What you are saying here is javascript variable set your property style.cssText to 'color:red'. 
If you change the line `HTMLattr.style.cssText = 'color:red;'` to `codeHTML[i].style.cssText = 'color:red;'` you are styling the DOM element which makes all the text in that element red.

I think that you're asking for is to style just the matched text. To do that you need to add another element which surrounds the text that you want to style, as below.

```js
var codeHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('code-html')

for (var i = 0; i < codeHTML.length; i+=1) {

  var str = codeHTML[i].textContent
  var HTMLattr = str.match(/".+"/g)
  
  if(HTMLattr) {
      let newSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
      let splitStr = str.split(HTMLattr[0]);
      newSpan.innerText = HTMLattr[0];
      newSpan.style.cssText = 'color:red;';
      codeHTML[i].innerHTML = "";
      codeHTML[i].append(splitStr[0]);
      codeHTML[i].appendChild(newSpan);
      codeHTML[i].append(splitStr[1]);
  }
}
```

```html
<code class="code code-html">
<span class="code-tag open">&lt;div class="test"&gt;</span>
Hi
<span class="code-tag closed">&lt;/div&gt;</span>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTMLattr is just an array with strings, it does not have any html attributes, you will need to find the dom containing those strings and add the css property to it.

```js
// CHANGE COLOUR OF MATCHED REGEX
var codeHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('code-html')

for (var i = 0; i < codeHTML.length; i += 1) {

  var str = codeHTML[i].textContent
  var HTMLattr = str.match(/".+"/g)

  if (HTMLattr) {
    HTMLattr.forEach(ele => {
      $("span:contains(" + ele + ")").css("color", "red");
    })
  }

  console.log(HTMLattr)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code class="code code-html">
<span class="code-tag open">&lt;div class="test"&gt;</span>
Hi
<span class="code-tag closed">&lt;/div&gt;</span>
</code>
```

Comment: I can't use jQuery for an answer sadly.

Comment: Also it's only the `"test"` part I want in red

Answer (score 0):

You can add the color class to the element wrapping your content, `codeHTML[i]`.

```js
// CHANGE COLOUR OF MATCHED REGEX
var codeHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('code-html')

for (var i = 0; i < codeHTML.length; i+=1) {

  var str = codeHTML[i].textContent;
  var HTMLattr = str.match(/".+"/g);

  if(HTMLattr) {
      codeHTML[i].style.cssText = 'color:red;'
  } 
}
```

```html
<code class="code code-html">
    <span class="code-tag open">&lt;div class="test"&gt;</span>
    Hi
    <span class="code-tag closed">&lt;/div&gt;</span>
</code>
```

Comment: It's only the actual `"test" ` text I want to change color though, not the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change `HTMLattr.style.cssText` to `codeHTML[i].style`, as `HTMLattr` is just the matched text and there's no element that's called `style.cssText`.

Comment: That will make all the text go red though. I just want the word `"test"` bit to go red

Comment: OK, that's not trivial as you will need to create a tag around `"test"` as you can only style whole tags in HTML.